# How to find the uploading time stamp on files

Tags: curl, wget

let's say we have a directory on a remote server, https://server/dir/... where team members are using this location to upload files for other purposes.  But from time to time, this server will be heavily over-loaded and we need to have it cleaned up.

I want to write a script that routinely check this server, and any file uploaded for this server for more than 14 days will be automatically cleaned-up.

The question I have is,  which command I find use to find out each file's uploading time ???

This is the command that I current use to find the file list remotely: 
"curl -XGET -u username/pwd https://server/dir"

Thanks for the help.

Jack